# What is proper way of linking C program with standard threads (<threads.h> from C11)?

Tags: c, multithreading, linker, pthreads, c11

I'm trying to learn how to use  in C11, so I've tried to compile that example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <threads.h>

int run(void *arg)
{
    printf("Hello world of C11 threads from thread %lu.\n", thrd_current());
    fflush(stdout);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    thrd_t thread;
    if (thrd_success != thrd_create(&thread, run, NULL))
    {
        perror("Error creating thread!");
        return 1;
    }

    int result;
    thrd_join(thread, &result);
    printf("Thread %lu returned %d at the end\n", thread, result);
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

The problem is that the program needs to be compiled with extra linker flags:

```
$ gcc --std=c17 main.c
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccEtxJ6l.o: in function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x66): undefined reference to `thrd_create'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text+0x90): undefined reference to `thrd_join'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But nowhere is information what flags should I use, I've noticed, that compilation with `-lpthread` flag is succesfull:

```
$ gcc --std=c17 main.c -lpthread && ./a.out 
Hello world of C11 threads from thread 140377624237824.
Thread 140377624237824 returned 0 at the end
```

But it does not mean that it is right flag.
I'm using gcc:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Arch Linux 9.3.0-1) 9.3.0
```

Comment: Try taking a look through threads.h.  Maybe it's implemented on top of pthreads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have decided to use < threads.h> on the Linux platform, you must link your program with -lpthread.

for example, if you are using GCC you will find the **join** implementation [here](https://code.woboq.org/gcc/libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/thread.cc.html#105) and you will also notice that it is just a call to [pthread_join](https://code.woboq.org/gcc/include/c++/7.2.1/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bits/gthr-default.h.html#__gthread_join).

Answer (score 1):

Please check this:

> If the macro constant **STDC_NO_THREADS**(C11) is defined by the compiler, the header  and all of the names listed here are not provided.

Comment: The flag is not provided:
#ifdef STDC_NO_THREADS
    puts("test");
#endif

Comment: it's actually `__STDC_NO_THREADS__`

Comment: this is also not provided in my compiler:)

Answer (score -2):

Why use thread.h? Its considered an inferior API. Use pthread.h instead which is the POSIX standard. The -lpthread flag is also used include pthread library during compilation. 
Man page of Pthread:
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man0/pthread.h.0p.html

Comment: But I want to create portable code between operation systems. Pthreads are rather not for Windows

Comment: A POSIX layer such as Cygwin would probably compile an app with #include <pthreads.h>

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/bb463209(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: There are some windows libraries that will allow for multithreading using pthread.h

Comment: @baziorek Microsoft's compiler isn't even C99 compliant.  Don't hold your breath on a C11-compliant compiler from them, much less one that implements the optional threads.h.

Comment: this nice C compiler is C11/C17 compatible and implement threads.h : http://www.smorgasbordet.com/pellesc/